# R - Having some trouble with plotting using time data

Tags: r

I am currently trying to write a forecasting algorithm in R, but I'm having an issue extracting my time data from a txt file.

I currently have a test text file with the following data

```
x
1 2010-01-01
2 2010-07-02
3 2010-08-03
4 2011-02-04
5 2011-11-05
6 2011-12-06
7 2012-06-07
8 2012-08-30
9 2013-04-16
10 2013-03-18
11 2014-02-22
12 2014-01-27
13 2015-12-15
14 2015-09-28
15 2016-05-04
16 2017-11-07
17 2017-09-22
18 2017-04-04
```

When I extract it and try to plot it with the following code:

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

Quantity <- c(read.table("....Path..../Quantity.txt"))
Time <- c(read.table("....Path..../Time.txt"))


x <- ts(as.Date(unlist(Time)))
y <- unlist(Quantity)


plot(x,y)
```

The resulting graph displays all the points on the graph correctly, except for the labels for time (which are 14500, 16000, and 17500). The labels should  show the dates from the file, but the way I see it, its probably treating the data as a maths sum (and does a calculation resulting in those values) and not dates.

I also have an issue that the time data is not being plotted in chronological order, but instead in the order from the files.

Here's the data from the other file just for reference:

```
x
1 5
2 3
3 8
4 4
5 0
6 5
7 2
8 7
9 4
10 2
11 6
12 8
13 4
14 7
15 8
16 9
17 4
18 6
```

How can I correct these 2 issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the many possible solutions.
I hope it can help you.

```
# A dataset with date and x values
# Important: the format of date is "character"
df <- structure(list(date = c("2010-01-01", "2010-07-02", "2010-08-03", 
"2011-02-04", "2011-11-05", "2011-12-06", "2012-06-07", "2012-08-30", 
"2013-04-16", "2013-03-18", "2014-02-22", "2014-01-27", "2015-12-15", 
"2015-09-28", "2016-05-04", "2017-11-07", "2017-09-22", "2017-04-04"
), x = c(5L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 6L)), .Names = c("date", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
str(df)

# Create a x vector with dates as rownames
x <- as.matrix(df$x)
rownames(x) <- df$date
# Convert in a xts object
library(xts)
x <- as.xts(x)

# Plot the xts object
plot(x, grid.col="white")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]To answer your `ggplot` question, using the data frame that Marco provided above, you would simply use:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = x)) + geom_line(group = 1)
```

Since you have only one group or one set of points, you must use the `group = 1` arg in `geom_line`.

One of the things I will point out is that your time series data has irregular periods, and you will have to make sure that you account for that in your time series object. Most time series packages have their own specialized functions for handling the data and plotting.